# Select total value from a table based on FK which is 3/4 layers up the chain

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following tables:

**Broker** (Id, ...)

**Desk** (Id, *BrokerId*, ...)

**Trader** (Id, *DeskId*, ...)

**Orders** (Id, *TraderId*, ...)

**Trade** (Id, *OrderId*, Trade Price, Trade Volume, Trade Time, ...)

The query needs to return me the **Broker Id**, **24hr traded vol**, **current month traded vol**, **year to date traded vol**. The query will take in 1 parameter (BrokerId), and if this parameter is NULL then it means fetch all the necessary info from all brokers, otherwise only from that specific broker.

*Table relationships*: Desk has FK with Broker (BrokerId), Trader has FK with Desk (DeskId), Orders has FK with Trader (TraderId), Trade has FK with Orders (OrderId).

I hope that I explained this clearly enough.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Expanding with sample data

**Broker** table

[image]

**Desk** table

[image]

**Trader** table

[image]

**Orders** table

[image]

**Trade** table

[image]

---

*Query examples*

BrokerId=1
should return the following result set:

| Broker Id | 24 hr vol | Curr month vol | YTD vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

BrokerId=3
should return the following result set:

| Broker Id | 24 hr vol | Curr month vol | YTD vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

BrokerId=NULL
should return the following result set:

| Broker Id | 24 hr vol | Curr month vol | YTD vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. What SQL query do you have so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you able to successfully join all of the tables listed?

Comment: Just provided some sample data and expected results, thanks